# Firefox popup 'Authentication Required' when accessing Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, firefox, authentication, proxy

One of the more recent updates to Firefox started to popup a message whenever I access StackOverflow from my work machine, along the lines of:

> 'The proxy moz-proxy://xxx:8080 is requesting a user name and password. The site says: "moz-proxy://xxx:8080"

The message consistently pops up 6 times, I can cancel all of them and the page looks fine. If I change to another SO page I get the same issue.

This is not a problem in Explorer and I haven't found any other website that gives me this problem - it's most irritating because SO is my first port of call for tech issues! I've had a hunt round the web and there are a couple of config suggestions (network.proxy.share_proxy_settings=false and network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies=false) that I have set but they make no difference. I am out of my depth here!

Any ideas?

Comment: this helped me. http://superuser.com/questions/398740/firefox-asks-for-proxy-details-but-only-when-accessing-facebook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved from the comment left by e19293001 which pointed to this: [Firefox asks for proxy details, but only when accessing facebook](https://superuser.com/questions/398740/firefox-asks-for-proxy-details-but-only-when-accessing-facebook)

> Go to the URL `about:config`, search for the key `network.websocket.enabled` and switch it to `false`.

Now able to access SO without those annoying popups!

Comment: shame this setting no longer exists in Firefox 61.0

Answer (score -3):

I put a new add-on on my Firefox and gave it auto-update permission and the next time I opened Mozilla Version57 I got the proxy "babble" and the same thing by closing and re-opening.

Simply open your add-ons and either disable all auto updates, or disable the auto update that is most recent like I did, or do them one at a time as a process of elimination.

Once you reverse the auto update causing the issue the problem is gone for good. In my case it was "setupVPN" add-on.